# Find two vectors whose sum is close to query vector

Tags: algorithm, hash, sum, approximation

Basically, this question is some sort of research question. I post it here to gain more hints from you. Suppose you have a set S of n d-dimension vectors. Given a d-dimension query vector, I want to find two vectors from S whose sum is close to the query vector, in term of cosine distance.

Right now, my solution is enumerating all possible combinations of S, results to n^2 possible sum-vectors. Then hash these n^2 vectors into b buckets using Local sensitive hashing. When given the query vector, we hash the query into one of the b buckets and check all the possible sum-vectors in that bucket, to see which one is closest. This will need O(b) space and O(n^2/b) searching time. This is just an space time trade off.

Is there any other good solutions ? Any hints are welcome ! I don't need the exact closest results, approximation results are more welcome!